# How to align to center a table created inside a code chunk in Quarto?

Tags: pandas, latex, r-markdown, quarto, beamer

I am using `quarto` with Python to produce some Beamer slides. I would like to generate a `Pandas` dataframe and have it a

````
## Test

```{python}
import pandas as pd
technologies = [ ["Spark",20000, "30days"], 
                 ["pandas",20000, "40days"], 
               ]
column_names=["Courses","Fee","Duration"]
row_label=["a","b"]
df=pd.DataFrame(technologies,columns=column_names,index=row_label)

df
```
````

This will generate the following output:

[image]

I'd like to have that table centered. What is the chunk option I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the code chunk that generates the table with pandoc divs `:::`, use the div-class `.center` and attribute `data-latex=""`.

````
---
title: "Center Align Code Output"
format: beamer
jupyter: python3
---

## Test

::: {.center  data-latex=""}

```{python}
import pandas as pd
technologies = [ ["Spark",20000, "30days"], 
                 ["pandas",20000, "40days"], 
               ]
column_names=["Courses","Fee","Duration"]
row_label=["a","b"]
df=pd.DataFrame(technologies,columns=column_names,index=row_label)

df
```

:::
````

---

[image: pandas table center aligned]

Answer (score 1):

Beamer will automatically centre tables. To be able to do it, it need a `table` environment around the tabular.

To force quarto to warp the tabular in a table environment, you could add a caption:

````
---
format: beamer
---

## Test

```{python}
import pandas as pd
technologies = [ ["Spark",20000, "30days"], 
                 ["pandas",20000, "40days"], 
               ]
column_names=["Courses","Fee","Duration"]
row_label=["a","b"]
df=pd.DataFrame(technologies,columns=column_names,index=row_label)

df.style.set_caption('')
```
````

[image]